How to take first row in spark scala dataframe if if status column is greater than threshold
I have a dataframe as shown below. I'm loading raw data from an HBase table once every hour. If the status is equal to 1 for more than 10 minutes continuously, then I need to take the first row for every hourly batch.... Similarly, I need to do this for other IDs as well.



ID
Timestamp
status




1
2021-01-01 10:00:00
1


1
2021-01-01 10:01:06
1


1
2021-01-01 10:02:18
1


1
2021-01-01 10:03:24
1


1
2021-01-01 10:04:30
1


1
2021-01-01 10:05:36
1


1
2021-01-01 11:06:00
1


1
2021-01-01 11:07:06
1


1
2021-01-01 11:08:12
1


1
2021-01-01 11:09:24
1


1
2021-01-01 11:10:30
1


1
2021-01-01 11:11:36
1



Expecting output like below



ID
Timestamp
status




1
2021-01-01 10:00:00
1



Can you please help me on this
NOTE: If the status value is change within threshold, then no need to consider it. For example, as shown below:



ID
Timestamp
status




1
2021-01-01 10:00:00
1


1
2021-01-01 10:01:06
1


1
2021-01-01 10:02:18
1


1
2021-01-01 10:03:24
1


1
2021-01-01 10:04:30
1


1
2021-01-01 10:05:36
2


1
2021-01-01 11:06:00
3


1
2021-01-01 11:07:06
1


1
2021-01-01 11:08:12
1


1
2021-01-01 11:09:24
1


1
2021-01-01 11:10:30
1


1
2021-01-01 11:11:36
1




What did you try so far? What's not working? Do you always want to consider fixed intervals of 10 minutes (0-10, 10-20, ...) or something else? A naive first implementation could be using groupBy.

I tried using lead and lag window functions, but they're not working. The interval is fixed 10minutes...status will change randomly sometimes will get 0,2,3 values also in status column...If the status is equal to 1 continuously for more than 10 minutes, then I need to take the first row.

I think this looks like the islands and gaps SQL problem (and pretty sure there are cleaner, more idiomatic solutions):
//build dataframe
val data = Seq((1,"2021-01-01T10:00:00",1),(1,"2021-01-01T10:01:06",1),(1,"2021-01-01T10:02:18",1),(1,"2021-01-01T10:03:24",1),(1,"2021-01-01T10:04:30",1),(1,"2021-01-01T10:05:36",2),(1,"2021-01-01T11:06:00",3),(1,"2021-01-01T11:07:06",1),(1,"2021-01-01T11:08:12",1),(1,"2021-01-01T11:09:24",1),(1,"2021-01-01T11:10:30",1),(1,"2021-01-01T11:11:36",1))


import org.apache.spark.sql.types._


val schema = StructType(List(StructField("id", IntegerType, true), StructField("timestamp", TimestampType, true), StructField("status", IntegerType, true)))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(schema.fieldNames: _*)

df.show()
+---+-------------------+------+
| id|          timestamp|status|
+---+-------------------+------+
|  1|2021-01-01T10:00:00|     1|
|  1|2021-01-01T10:01:06|     1|
|  1|2021-01-01T10:02:18|     1|
|  1|2021-01-01T10:03:24|     1|
|  1|2021-01-01T10:04:30|     1|
|  1|2021-01-01T10:05:36|     2|
|  1|2021-01-01T11:06:00|     3|
|  1|2021-01-01T11:07:06|     1|
|  1|2021-01-01T11:08:12|     1|
|  1|2021-01-01T11:09:24|     1|
|  1|2021-01-01T11:10:30|     1|
|  1|2021-01-01T11:11:36|     1|
+---+-------------------+------+


df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: integer (nullable = false)
 
 // identify contigous regions by status then get the duration of that status
 
 df.withColumn("id_sequence", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(col("id")).orderBy(col("timestamp").asc))).
 withColumn("id_and_status", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(col("id"), col("status")).orderBy(col("timestamp").asc))).
 withColumn("group", col("id_sequence") - col("id_and_status")).
 withColumn("group_max", max(col("timestamp")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("id"),col("group"))).cast(TimestampType)).
 withColumn("group_min", min(col("timestamp")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("id"),col("group"))).cast(TimestampType)).
 withColumn("difference_in_mins", (unix_timestamp(col("group_max")) - unix_timestamp(col("group_min"))) / 60).
 orderBy(col("id"), col("timestamp").asc).
 show()
 
+---+-------------------+------+-----------+-------------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| id|          timestamp|status|id_sequence|id_and_status|group|          group_max|          group_min|difference_in_mins|
+---+-------------------+------+-----------+-------------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|  1|2021-01-01T10:00:00|     1|          1|            1|    0|2021-01-01 10:04:30|2021-01-01 10:00:00|               4.5|
|  1|2021-01-01T10:01:06|     1|          2|            2|    0|2021-01-01 10:04:30|2021-01-01 10:00:00|               4.5|
|  1|2021-01-01T10:02:18|     1|          3|            3|    0|2021-01-01 10:04:30|2021-01-01 10:00:00|               4.5|
|  1|2021-01-01T10:03:24|     1|          4|            4|    0|2021-01-01 10:04:30|2021-01-01 10:00:00|               4.5|
|  1|2021-01-01T10:04:30|     1|          5|            5|    0|2021-01-01 10:04:30|2021-01-01 10:00:00|               4.5|
|  1|2021-01-01T10:05:36|     2|          6|            1|    5|2021-01-01 10:05:36|2021-01-01 10:05:36|               0.0|
|  1|2021-01-01T11:06:00|     3|          7|            1|    6|2021-01-01 11:06:00|2021-01-01 11:06:00|               0.0|
|  1|2021-01-01T11:07:06|     1|          8|            6|    2|2021-01-01 11:11:36|2021-01-01 11:07:06|               4.5|
|  1|2021-01-01T11:08:12|     1|          9|            7|    2|2021-01-01 11:11:36|2021-01-01 11:07:06|               4.5|
|  1|2021-01-01T11:09:24|     1|         10|            8|    2|2021-01-01 11:11:36|2021-01-01 11:07:06|               4.5|
|  1|2021-01-01T11:10:30|     1|         11|            9|    2|2021-01-01 11:11:36|2021-01-01 11:07:06|               4.5|
|  1|2021-01-01T11:11:36|     1|         12|           10|    2|2021-01-01 11:11:36|2021-01-01 11:07:06|               4.5|
+---+-------------------+------+-----------+-------------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+

I didn't go any further but I think it is relatively simple to filter "difference_in_mins" for values greater than 10 mins and then grab the first record.
Hope this helps.

Thank you so much @SD_ Its working... :)
